# including .replace function with regex map approach in existing script

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, str-replace

I have the following script:

```
$(".balkenclosed").click(function() {
window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
return false;
});
```

I try to add a .replace function like this:

```
var replace = new Map([
/ [^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/ig, "", $id
]),
id = a;
replace.forEach(function(value, key){
id = id.replace(key, value);
});
```

It should replace invalid characters in the id of divs like this one:

```
<div class="balken"><div class="balkenopen"><a id="2our$ / team/2$"
style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="#2our$ / team/2$">
our team</a></div></div>
```

The result in this case should be id:"our_team" and href:"our_team"

My approach doesn't work and I feel like I'm completely wrong. 
I would really appreciate any hint into the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written jquery, which will produce your desired result, you can refine though. Hope this will help you.

> Please consider that it will search for entire anchor tag and replace if matches found. Replace `$(a)` with the more appropriate selector for the specific search.

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var id = self.attr('id');
  var href = self.attr('href');
  if (id)
    self.attr('id', stripEverything(id, '_'));
  if (href)
    self.attr('href', '#'+stripEverything(href, '_'));
});

function stripEverything(string, replaceSpaceWith) {
  return string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]+/g, '').split(' ').filter(function(e) {
    return e
  }).join(replaceSpaceWith);
}
```

You can look the solution at [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/5wwcpv0a/4/)

Comment: dear Rajan, thank you very much for your answer and your help. I tested your code and it works well. 
can you give me a hint how I can keep the leading # in the href?

Comment: just add `#` in ` self.attr('href', stripEverything(href, '_'));` which will be like `self.attr('href', '#'+stripEverything(href, '_'));`

Comment: @undefined I have updated the answer as well as the fiddle, and please accept answer if it satisfies your need and upvote it, :)

Comment: dear Rajan, thank you again for your answer and the edit. Due to my low rep (sadly I never get upvotes on my questions) my upvote on your answer wont be not displayed, sorry for that. But I accepted your answer :)
you can see my solution here: [https://codepen.io/undefined999/pen/VyyQVw]
I dont want to bother you but maybe you have an idea how I can replace special characters like ä with ae and so on?

Comment: @undefined, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366125/include-special-characters-like-%C3%B6-%C3%A4-%C3%BC-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thanks Rajan, I found and implemented a working solution already. same pen as above. Thank you very much for your help, you're really a kind and nice guy :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `value` as the regex

```
var replace = [
   /[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/ig, ""
];
replace.forEach(function(value, key){
  id = id.replace( value, "");
});
```

In fact, looking at the content of replace, simply

```
id = id.replace( replace[0], replace[1]);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Am I correct with my guess that you mean with `replace[0], replace[1]` that it replace the first and the second id inside the div?
And then just replace the line `id = id.replace( value, "");` with `id = id.replace( replace[0], replace[1]);` ?

Comment: No, I meant that you only need to use `id = id.replace( replace[0], replace[1]);` and nothing else. Also observe that `replace`'s initialization has changed from `map` to a simple array.